# Search segment and append value at the end

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

In a file I want to append a string after the specific segment with key "sys-mgmt-agent".
This is the file content:

```
  sys-mgmt-agent:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z

  edge-orchestrator:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
```

This is the expected result:

```
  sys-mgmt-agent:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
    MY STRING

  edge-orchestrator:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
```

I found the segment using sed command: `sed -n '/sys-mgmt-agent:/,/^\s*$/p' <file>` but I can't append my string.

Comment: IMHO experts always advise to use `yq` like tools which understands yaml files better. Do you have `yq` in your system or you could install it? Based on your response people could provide you guidance here.

Comment: No, I can't install a software in remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sed` idea that builds on OPs `sed` attempt:

```
$ mystring='MY STRING'
$ sed "/sys-mgmt-agent:/,/^$/{/^$/i\    ${mystring}
}" mydata
```

Where:

- `/sys-mgmt-agent/,/^$/` - range to search for
- `{...}` - commands to apply to matching range
- `/^$/i\    ${mystring}` - at the blank line insert a new line "    MY STRING"

**NOTE**: The `i\    ${mystring}` can't have anything after it on the same line hence the 2-line solution; I'm open to suggestions on how to collapse this into a single line.

---

**UPDATE**: @potong's suggestion for using `-e` flags to piece together a one-line solution works with the addition of double quotes around `${mystring}`:

```
$ mystring='MY STRING'
$ sed -e '/sys-mgmt-agent:/,/^$/{/^$/i\    '"${mystring}" -e '}' mydata
```

---

The above generates:

```
  sys-mgmt-agent:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
    MY STRING

  edge-orchestrator:
    networks:
     edgex-network:
       aliases:
           - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
      - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
      - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
```

Comment: Thanks, please let me know if there is a way to use the command in single line.

Comment: @sarjaana you might try: `sed -e '/sys-mgmt-agent:/,/^$/{/^$/i\    '${mystring} -e '}' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/sys-mgmt-agent:/{:a;/:$/h;n;/\S/{$!ba;p};x;s/\S.*/MY STRING/p;x;$d}' file
```

N.B. if `MY STRING` contains `/`'s these must be escaped/quoted i.e. `\/`. This also indents to the depth of the last stanza.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OP insists on using basic commands avialable under `bash`
- input is nicely formatted as presented
- if `sys-mgmt-agent:` shows up more than once the desired string is to be appended to each segment
- there is at least one blank line between segments

One `awk` solution:

```
$ mystring="MY STRING"                         # string to be appended to segment
$ awk -v ms="${mystring}" '                    # pass ${mystring} as awk variable "ms" 
/sys-mgmt-agent:/ { foundit=1 }                # if line contains "sys-mgmt-agent:" then set our flag
/^$/ && foundit { printf "    %s\n\n", ms      # if blank line and foundit=1 then print our string plus a new blank line
                  foundit=0                    # reset our flag
                  next                         # go to next input line
                }
                { print }                      # print all other lines as is
' mydata                                       # assuming input data is in file named "mydata"
```

The above generates:

```
sys-mgmt-agent:
  networks:
   edgex-network:
     aliases:
         - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes:
    - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
    - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
    - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
  MY STRING

edge-orchestrator:
  networks:
   edgex-network:
     aliases:
         - edgex-sys-mgmt-agent
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes:
    - /proc/uptime:/proc/uptime
    - /var/log/auth.log:/var/log/auth.log
    - ${HOST_SECURITY_FILE_PATH}edgex-redis:/tmp/edgex/secrets/edgex-redis:z
```